# Firebase Realtime Database Spaces in Keys

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have a database with hundreds of Node objects, all of which are named with spaces in their name. I sometimes have to go into one of these keys using console on my laptop to edit subordinate values.

Since the last time I tried this, for some reason instead of the key opening up in it's own page as 'Some Node' with it's appropriate key/values underneath, editable, it is showing up as 'Some%20Node' which is causing it to not be able to find the values underneath.

If instead of 'clicking into' the key to edit it, I simply expand the key node, the subordinate keys/values are present, so data is present. My Application is able to read and write to these nodes.

Is there anything I can do or is this a Firebase bug that was recently introduced?

Their support page says everything in Realtime DB is working smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you found a bug in the Firebase console for the Realtime Database. Please [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with the Firebase support team.

This type of problem would not be reported on the status page, as it's not a production outage.

Comment: I filed a bug report. Case number 00033755 was created. Thanks Frank!